# Extraordinarily slow printing to inkjet from Java

Tags: java, performance, printing, delay

I'm trying to output a very simple .txt file to an HP Photosmart Inkjet Printer. The command to print is issued when a button in the UI is pressed. It works, but disastrously slowly. The printer takes the paper and displays "printing" on its screen within seconds, but it's then a good five minutes before the printing actually takes place. It must be something in the code, as other print tasks from other programs, even when printing the same .txt file, are happening at normal speed.

My code (for the printing only) is as follows:

```
     PrintRequestAttributeSet aset=new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
           aset.add(OrientationRequested.LANDSCAPE);
           aset.add(new Copies(1));
           aset.add(Sides.DUPLEX);
           aset.add(MediaSizeName.NA_LETTER);
           aset.add(new NumberUp(2));
           aset.add(Finishings.NONE);

                 FileInputStream textStream;
                   try{
                      textStream = new FileInputStream(file_name);
                      DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
                      Doc mydoc = new SimpleDoc(textStream, flavor, null);
          PrintService[] services=PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(flavor, aset);
          PrintService defaultService =PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
                      if(services.length == 0) {
                      if(defaultService == null) {
                              //no printer found
                      } else {
                              //print using default
                     DocPrintJob job = defaultService.createPrintJob();
                            try{
                                job.print(mydoc, aset);
                                }
                            catch(Exception err){

                                }
                               }
                               } else {
                               PrintService service = ServiceUI.printDialog(null, 200,                       200, services, defaultService, flavor, aset);
                                if (service != null){
                                DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();
                                job.print(mydoc, aset);
                                      }
                                    }
                                  }
                                catch(Exception err){

                                     }
```

Now I ultimately intend to use this on a Thermal receipt printer, which I (without any concrete reason) presume will be faster, but still, even if it takes a tenth of the time this takes, it's too long. Is there anything in my code that is causing this hideous slowness? I have tinkered with the MediaSizeName, Sides, INPUT_STREAM etc, all to either no effect, or resulting in no printing at all. Does anyone have any idea as to how I might hurry this process up? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try code formatting in your IDE. This is very often accelerated by the keystroke: `Ctrl-Shift-F` or `Cmd-Shift-F` on Mac.

Comment: Oh nice. Thanks, didn't know 'bout that! Apologies for the ugly state of the code above ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check how the document is detected.  For some reason it could be being converted to raster/graphics mode.  Additionally, make `textStream` buffered.  Like in

```
InputStream textStream;
textStream= new BufferedInputStream( new FileInputStream(file_name) );
```

In fact, now that I see you are streaming the file, I think this could also be affecting detection.  Try other `DocFlavor`s if you can.  Force text mode no matter what it takes! :-)

Comment: That could make sense. The printout, when it is eventually received, is very cleanly printed, as if it was a high res image, rather than something bashed out of notepad. However, I'm a total noob - how might I find out the detection method being used on the file?